# Accessing status bar with pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis

I made a custom map tool plugin with pygis like this:

```
class myTool:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.mapTool = mapTool(self.canvas)
        ....

class mapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint)
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QGis.Polygon )
        ....
```

And i make some calculations inside the mapTool class and i want to display the results into Qgis status bar, but i haven't found a way to accsess the status bar from the mapTool class because it uses the canvas attribute not the iface attribute.

Comment: do you mean the messagebar?

Comment: All about communicating with user is explain here http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html

Comment: No i mean status bar, where the coordinates are displayed, and as i described I don't have access to iface from mapTool class

Answer (score 1):

you can access the message bar with this:

```
result = "my result" # an example 
self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info:", "I did something and this is the result: %s" % result, level=QgsMessageBar.SUCCESS,  duration=3)
```

The pushMessage method takes 4 arguments:

- The first argument  is the title and will show in **bold**
- The second argument is the message itself you can insert variable text on it and even widgets
- the last argument is the message level. You can choose between SUCCESS, INFO, WARNING and CRITICAL
- duration Argument, which controls, how long a message is shown

you can read the full explanation on the [API site for pyqgis QgsMessageBar Class](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsMessageBar.html)

Comment: I dont want to access the message bar, I want to acces the status bar. And as i described I don't have access to iface.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out the solution on my own, just needed some python logic.

```
statusBar = ""   # make new variable outside the classes
class MyTool:
    global statusBar   # make it global inside the class
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        global statusBar   # make it global inside the method
        statusBar = self.iface.mainWindow().statusBar()   # give a new value to statusBar variable
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.mapTool = mapTool(self.canvas)
        ....

class MapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint)
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QGis.Polygon )
        ....

   def someMethod(self):
       ...
       statusBar.showMessage("my message")   # use status bar
       ...
```

Still don't know if it is the best solution but at least it is working.